# How to map Java entity to Oracle Object Type

Tags: java, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I have implemented a stored procedure within the Oracle database. This procedure accepts a single parameter, performs various operations, and outputs a result. Below is the procedure:

`create or replace procedure my_proc(p_Card_Transaction in Card_Transaction, p_result out varchar2) is begin p_result := 'Ok'; end my_proc;`

As you can observe, the parameter type is an Oracle Object Type. The definition of this object type in Oracle is as follows:

`create type Card_Transaction as object ( card_id   VARCHAR2(50), amount    Number );`

In my Spring application, I have an entity defined as follows:

`public class CardTransaction { String card_id; Double amount; }`

I'm utilizing Spring Data JPA and attempting to map my Java CardTransaction entity to the Oracle object type Card_Transaction by using @NamedStoredProcedureQuery. However, I'm encountering issues, and I'm seeking assistance from anyone who has successfully resolved a similar problem.

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help :

1 : You need to create an Oracle Object Type (OOT) like you did up there

```
CREATE TYPE CardTransaction AS OBJECT (
    cardId VARCHAR2(50),
    amount NUMBER
);
```

2 : Create a Java class that corresponds to the OOT :

```
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class CardTransaction{
    private String cardId;
    private Integer amount;
}
```

Note : Embeddable is used in JPA to indicate that the class can be embedded in another entity.

2.1 : Hint for the futur :) Example that can help you by using the CardTransaction as Type in your entity

```
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Transaction {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Embedded
    private CardTransaction cardTransaction;
}
```

3 : Edit your persistance.xml file

```
<persistence-unit name="yourPersistenceUnitName" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.example.CardTransaction</class>
    <class>com.example.Transaction</class>
    <!-- Other configurations -->
</persistence-unit>
```

Now you can use your EntityManager to persist and retrieve instances of your entities